Firefox KDE notifications are displayed in middle of screen and capture focus
In KDE browser notifications from Firefox since a while ago started to display in the center of the screen instead of in a corner and steal the focus (so if I'm writing something the input field loses focus when the notification is displayed). This wasn't the case earlier.
I'm running Debian 12 with KDE Plasma 5.27.5.
I already tried going to System Settings -> Notifications -> Choose Custom Position where I selected the corner where they used to display but that didn't change where the browser notifications display and there is no setting about the focus (I read notifications are not supposed to capture focus so there is no need for such a setting). I showed some notifications with a Test Web Push Notifications website but they display in the center. I tested notify-send te st and that notification displays in the corner where I configured it. In Firefox there are no notification settings other than which websites have notifications allowed or blocked.
I'm sandboxing the firefox with firejail maybe it has to do with that but again it used to work and I didn't change the firejail profile in the meantime. Do other users with Debian 12 and KDE also have this issue? It may also have to do with another screen that I connect to sometimes which has another resolution (that display is currently not enabled in display settings). If it's a bug I don't know if it's in firefox, kde, firejail, or something else so I hope this is a known problem and maybe already solved by somebody.
